# How is it possible Resizable Android Widget programming At Home Screen?

Tags: android, android-widget

Tap and hold the widget and then User can Re-size widget on Home Screen

Comment: What are you asking? I could not understand.

Comment: please elaborate. Whats you tried so far? do you have some finding on google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
```

> The resizeMode attribute specifies the rules by which a widget can be resized. You use this attribute to make homescreen widgets resizeable—horizontally, vertically, or on both axes. Users touch-hold a widget to show its resize handles, then drag the horizontal and/or vertical handles to change the size on the layout grid. Values for the resizeMode attribute include "horizontal", "vertical", and "none". To declare a widget as resizeable horizontally and vertically, supply the value "horizontal|vertical". Introduced in Android 3.1.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

You can find here more info about widgets and resizing.

Comment: Always at your sevice) So, mark the answer as correct for future user searchings on the same topic.